# How to validate the effect of the type of Task on participants' performance using count data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, glmm, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

We conducted a user testing with two groups of participants (Group_A, Group_B).

Group_A performed Task_A (a writing) under Condition_A.

Group_B performed Task_B (a writing) under Condition_B.

Group_A and Group_B refer to two classrooms (pre-existing groups).

The Task_A was slightly different from Task_B (a slightly different subject for the writing).

Task_A and Task_B were randomly assigned to Group_A and Group_B, respectively.

The variable Condition with two levels: Condition_A (treatment) and Condition_B (control) was the main factor of study.
But the difference in the Task could affect the outcomes of the participants between Group_A and Group_B.

We quantified a number of dependents measures (DM).
DM were mainly **count** (frequency) data.

- We conducted statistical analysis using nonparametric Mann–Whitney U to evaluate the difference between groups, for two-way analyses of count data.
- We used the Generalized Linear Mixed-effects Model (GLMM) for factorial analyses of count data.

In retrospect, we would like to evaluate the effect of the difference of the **Task** between Group_A and Group_B.

What are the best approaches to validate whether the type of the **task** affected (or not) the outcomes of the participants in Group_A and Group_B?

Comment: How where the two groups made? By randomization, or they were pre-existing groups?

Comment: Group_A and Group_B refer to two classrooms (pre-existing groups). Task_A and Task_B were randomly assigned to Group_A and Group_B.

Comment: We had also another variable: Condition_A (treatment) and Condition_B (control) —(just edited the question). The variable Condition is the main independent factor of our study. But the difference in the Task could affect the outcomes of the participants between Group_A and Group_B.

Comment: Please add all this new information as an edit to the post. Knowing how the groups were made is important! We do want posts to be self-contained, and comments are easily overlooked, and can be removed!

Comment: Thank you, @kjetilbhalvorsen, I just updated the question.